# Avaya Aurora Contact Center dll files?

Tags: c#, server, avaya

I need the Nortel.CCT and Nortel.CCT.Lite dll reference for a c# project.

I searched the avaya dev forum and searched with google, but no luck.

How can I download these files?

thanks!

Comment: Asking for offsite resources is off topic.

Answer (score 1):

You can download it from www.devconnectprogram.com

Go to "Downloads -> CCT .NET API"

All documentation can also be found here.

If you are asked for login credentials, you can register free of charge.